# How to intercept MobileFirst adapter's resource method call

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Is it possible to intercept MobileFirst adapter's resource method call? The purpose of such intercepting is adding common logic for all adapter's resource methods into one place (e.g. appending HTTP response with particular headers).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can "intercept it", but you can just write your code in a way that all adapter calls first go through some helper function where you add your required headers before "releasing" the call from the client and have it sent to the server.